# Falha de conversão de String para StringStream

Tags: delphi

Estou tendo um problema na conversão do conteúdo de uma String para StringStream.
O conteúdo da string é esse:

> 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

O código que estou usando para a conversão é esse:

```
var
  lStr: TStringStream;
  sInfo: WideString;
begin
  lStr := TStringStream.Create(sInfo);
end;
```

Porém, após esse "create", a variável *lStr* fica zerada.

Acredito que seja pelo fato de conter caracteres de escape e não estou sabendo como tratar isso na string.

Comment: após o create, simulando aqui, testei o `lStr.DataString` e esta correto, como esta testando o conteúdo da `lStr`?

Comment: Utilizando o debug, após o create eu coloco o mouse sobre a variável e aparece apenas "()". Será que devo usar outra forma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando utilizado o `TStringStream` o Delphi converte a string em bytes,
dessa forma não conseguimos depurar diretamente com o cursor do mouse.

Porem, a string ainda existe dentro da variável stream, mas o que utiliza-se são os bytes (string formatada em binário).

Para comparar pode utilizar a propriedade `DataString`.

```
if lStr.DataString = sInfo then
  ...
```

Comment: Té certo... muito obrigado pela ajuda!